# can we use autoencoders for text data

Tags: autoencoder

I am doing my project based on health care.I am going to train my autoencoders with the symptoms and the diseases i.e my input is in textual form. Will that work? (I am using Rstudio).Please anyone help me with this

Comment: Welcome to SO. However, as written, your question is too broad. Please try something and come back when you get stuck.

Answer (score 9):

You have to convert the text to **vectors/number**s. To do this traditional approaches like Bag of words, Tf-Idf will help but the latest Neural Word Embedding like **Word2Vec, RNN** Language model etc are the best techniques to obtain numeric representation of text.
Please use any Neural Word Embedding technique and convert the text(word `level[word2vec], document level[doc2vec])` into **numbers/vectors**.
Now these vectors come with some dimension and to compress this representation to even smaller dimension u can use **AutoEncode**r.
Feel Free to ask any other information required.
Try using Python for these tasks as it has the latest packages.

Comment: Do you see a problem in applying the autoencoder to a matrix that consist on the bag of words representation concatenated with other continuous features (like age or other counts)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Autoencoder on Textual data as explained [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/encoder-decoder-models-text-summarization-keras/).

Autoencoder usually worked better on image data but recent approaches changed the autoencoder in a way it is also good on the text data.

have a look at [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1705.02033).

the code is also available in GitHub.